# Nginx URL Redirection

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a website running on port 80 as a `default_server`, its root in the config file is `root /var/www/sample1/current` and I can access it through `www.sample1.com`, and I have one more website on the same server:

- `/var/www/sample2/current`

So I need to call the second website `/var/www/sample2/current` through `www.sample1.com/sample2` on the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the http://nginx.org/r/alias directive.

```
root /var/www/sample1/current;

location ^~ /sample2 {
    alias /var/www/sample2/current;
}
```

Comment: Then you need to set permissions on your files and folders so that NGINX can access them.